# Create javascript variable from php array and create a table in the same js

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I am trying to create a table in html by processing some sql queries in a php file.

After querying from sql db, array is json_encoded as shown below:

```
["ne_2002","ne_9007"]
["ne_2002","ne_9008"]
["ne_2002","ne_2003","ne_9004"]
["ne_2002","ne_8005","ne_8006","ne_9009"]
```

This is the output I am getting in index.html

I need to make it as variable shown below to create a table in the same html:

```
        var obj = [
        {
        columnA: 'ne_2002', 
        columnB: 'ne_9007',
    columnC: '',
        columnD: ''

}, 
    {
     columnA: 'ne_2002', 
    columnB: 'ne_9008',
    columnC: '',
        columnD: ''

}, 

    {
  columnA: 'ne_2002', 
    columnB: 'ne_2003',
    columnC: 'ne_9004',
        columnD: ''

}, 



    {
  columnA: 'ne_2002', 
    columnB: 'ne_8005',
    columnC: 'ne_8006',
        columnD: 'ne_9009'

}

];
```

Comment: You'll probably need to convert the "sql db array" (which I'm assuming is an indexed array), into an associative array first. Then if you pass it into `json_encode` it should create the correct JS object structure rather than an indexed array

Comment: hi, im new to coding. below is the query i am executing. I have looped few foreach, and one is shown. How I can get assosiative array from this? sorry for troubling you.   $far_end_qu_7=mysql_query("SELECT conn_ne_id_f FROM conn_data WHERE conn_ne_id_n='$v6'",$con) or die(mysql_error());
while($far_end_qu_7_result_arr=mysql_fetch_row($far_end_qu_7)){
 
  foreach ($far_end_qu_7_result_arr as $v7)
  {
  array_push($path_array_hop6, $n_ne_id,$v0, $v1, $v2,$v3, $v4, $v5, $v6, $v7);

Comment: Sorry not quite sure what all your variables are referring to, but you'll probably have to do something like this in your `foreach` loop: `foreach ($far_end_qu_7_result_arr as $v7) { array_push($path_array_hop6, array("columnA" => $n_ne_id, "columnD" => $v7); }`. What we're doing here is adding a new associative array with all your column data, into the original json array (assuming that is `$path_array_hop6`)